# Is row not empty then go to next row to paste data based on current date in Column

Tags: vba, range

I am new to VBA, so trying to to execute this code, I am able to run the code in the row where I want it but i want to run the code for next 2 row as well but don't know how to apply logic to go next available row. As I want to copy data for 3 times for the same date. The code as follows which generate upon button click.

Adding additional info: thanks everyone for your input and your time, much appreciated for your help.

This is great, I learn new things however, as I am updating data reading three times a day so, I want to copy my reading data from the row where I am updating three times a day so for tracking purpose I want to copy reading data the rows below as per data.

On click reading data should copy to the row for the morning, afternoon and evening reading as you can see from sample image herewith sample format

[Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUVIk.png)

I hope I am able to explain my query as I am not a tech person but trying my best.

Thanking you for your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Rg As Range
   Set Rg = Me.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(Application.Text(Date, [A16].NumberFormat), [A17], xlValues)
   
     If Rg Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Today's Date Not Found. Please check the 'Date Received'" Else Rg(1, 2).Resize(, 24).Value2 = [B16:W16].Value2: Set Rg = Nothing
     
           
    ' If Rg Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Today's Date Not Found. Please check the 'Date Received'" Else Rg(2, 2).Resize(, 24).Value2 = [B16:W16].Value2: Set Rg = Nothing
    ' If Rg Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Today's Date Not Found. Please check the 'Date Received'" Else Rg(3, 2).Resize(, 24).Value2 = [B16:W16].Value2: Set Rg = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the `Offset` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) of the range, as in `Rg.Offset`.

Comment: If possible it's best to write code on multiple lines - putting an `If Then Else` on one line (and then another statement after that) makes it more difficult to follow.

Comment: I tried but it didn't working for me.

Comment: Any help in my case..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you can use `Resize()` to fill 3 rows instead of only one.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Rg As Range, copyRange As Range
    
    Set Rg = Nothing
    Set Rg = Me.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(Application.Text(Date, [A16].NumberFormat), [A17], xlValues)
   
    If Rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Today's Date Not Found. Please check the 'Date Received'"
    Else
        Set copyRange = [B16:W16]
        Rg.Offset(0, 1).Resize(3, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value2 = [B16:W16].Value2
    End If
     
End Sub
```